# Remove duplicate elements from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to remove all the duplicate elements from the following array of objects and form a new array.

```
let arr = [{item: 'abc'},{item: 'def'},{item: 'abc'},{item: 'ghi'}];
```

expected output:

```
let newArr =  [{item: 'abc'},{item: 'def'},{item: 'ghi'}];
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. Do you have a specific question? _"How can I do this"_ isn't a specific programming question. Please don't spam tags. This "question" isn't related to React.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out items that have a previous matching item

```js
let arr = [{item: 'abc'},{item: 'def'},{item: 'abc'},{item: 'ghi'}];

let newArray = arr.filter((val, index) => !arr.find((val2, index2) => val.item === val2.item && index > index2));

console.log(newArray);
```